# How to show single list button data on each button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

How to show data on each button's click event?

Hi, I have an item list. In the list there a toggle button, when I click a single button all the list's data show.

I want to show a single item data.

More info view this snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".item-btn").click(function(){
    $(".item-price").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
li {
    list-style:none;
    background:#ddd;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    padding:5px;
}

.item-price {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-list">
    <ul class="lict-block">
        <li class="item">
            <div class="item-img"></div>
            <div class="item-content">
                <div class="item-btn">Show Price</div>
                <div class="item-price">
                    <h3>23.66</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
            <div class="item-img"></div>
            <div class="item-content">
                <div class="item-btn">Show Price</div>
                <div class="item-price">
                    <h3>23.66</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
            <div class="item-img"></div>
            <div class="item-content">
                <div class="item-btn">Show Price</div>
                <div class="item-price">
                    <h3>23.66</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.siblings()` to select the element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".item-btn").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.item-price').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  background: #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.item-price {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="main-list">
  <ul class="lict-block">
    <li class="item">
      <div class="item-img"></div>
      <div class="item-content">
        <div class="item-btn">Show Price</div>
        <div class="item-price">
          <h3>23.66</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <div class="item-img"></div>
      <div class="item-content">
        <div class="item-btn">Show Price</div>
        <div class="item-price">
          <h3>23.66</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <div class="item-img"></div>
      <div class="item-content">
        <div class="item-btn">Show Price</div>
        <div class="item-price">
          <h3>23.66</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to use `$(this).parent().find('item-price')` because it will also work when your HTML code position changed so better to use this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".item-btn").click(function() {
    $('.item-price').hide();
    $(this).parent().find('.item-price').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  background: #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.item-price {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="main-list">
  <ul class="lict-block">
    <li class="item">
      <div class="item-img"></div>
      <div class="item-content">
        <div class="item-btn">Show Price</div>
        <div class="item-price">
          <h3>23.66</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <div class="item-img"></div>
      <div class="item-content">
        <div class="item-btn">Show Price</div>
        <div class="item-price">
          <h3>23.66</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <div class="item-img"></div>
      <div class="item-content">
        <div class="item-btn">Show Price</div>
        <div class="item-price">
          <h3>23.66</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @harry before you toggle current one you can hide other open prices it will look cool

Answer (score 2):

You should use `$(this)` and `.next()` So you must access the clicked element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".item-btn").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".item-price").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
li{
list-style:none;
background:#ddd;
margin-bottom:30px;
padding:5px;
}
.item-price{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="main-list">
 <ul class="lict-block">
  <li class="item">
   <div class="item-img"></div>
   <div class="item-content">
    <div class="item-btn">Show Price</div>
    <div class="item-price">
     <h3>23.66</h3>
    </div>
   </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
   <div class="item-img"></div>
   <div class="item-content">
    <div class="item-btn">Show Price</div>
    <div class="item-price">
     <h3>23.66</h3>
    </div>
   </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
   <div class="item-img"></div>
   <div class="item-content">
    <div class="item-btn">Show Price</div>
    <div class="item-price">
     <h3>23.66</h3>
    </div>
   </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```